# How to make title size bigger than article in XML Viewer

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, xml, xml-viewer-web-part

I am using an RSS feed in my XML viewer web part to display a company's blog from their website. It works, but the only problem is that the title of the article is the same font size as the article itself and I would like to make it larger. Here is the XSL code that I am using now

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:param name="TITLE"/>
<xsl:template match="rss">
  <div style="background:#fff; padding:0; font-size:10px;">
      <xsl:for-each select="channel/item">
        <a href="{link}" target="_new"><xsl:value-of select="title"/></a><br/>    
        <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="description"/><br/>
      </xsl:for-each>
  </div>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="description"><xsl:value-of select="."/><br/></xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
<xsl:for-each select="channel/item">
        <h1><a href="{link}" target="_new"><xsl:value-of select="title"/></a></h1><br/>    
        <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="description"/><br/>
      </xsl:for-each>
```

or

```
<xsl:for-each select="channel/item">
        <h2><a href="{link}" target="_new"><xsl:value-of select="title"/></a></h2><br/>    
        <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="description"/><br/>
      </xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Thank you! Any way you can answer this question too? http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/111626/different-articles-in-xml-viewer-web-part-have-different-font-sizes-and-styles

Sorry, I'm new to Sharepoint and am just struggling to learn everything right now.