# Different articles in XML Viewer Web Part have different font sizes and styles

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, xml, xml-viewer-web-part

I am using an XML Viewer Web Part to display an RSS Feed from a blog on a company website. The problem is that in the viewer, different articles have a different font size and style, whereas I would like them to all be in the same size and font. Here is the XSL code I'm using:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:param name="TITLE"/>
<xsl:template match="rss">
  <div style="background:#fff; padding:0; font-size:12px;">
       <xsl:for-each select="channel/item">
        <h1><a href="{link}" target="_new"><xsl:value-of select="title"/></a></h1><br/>    
        <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="description"/><br/>
      </xsl:for-each>
  </div>
</xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="description"><xsl:value-of select="."/><br/></xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Any idea how to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You'd want to wrap your description like this:

```
<div style="font-size:12px; font-family:arial;">
  <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="description"/>
</div>
```

This may or may not work properly if the descriptions from the feed have inline styling as those would take priority over styles from the div wrapper.

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't work. Is there any way to get around the inline styling?